# How does Heroku "move" dynos?

Tags: heroku

In [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/erosion-resistance#erosion-is-a-problem-for-apps) it says:

> The dyno manager keeps your app’s dyno formation running without any
>   manual intervention. It restarts crashed dynos automatically, and
>   moves your dynos to new locations automatically and instantly whenever
>   a failure in the underlying hardware occurs.

I'm wondering what "move" means exactly? I know when a variable changes heroku restarts a dyno with new settings, but "moving" implies that the dyno keeps running while its ephemeral file system is changed if there is a storage failure. But what if there is a RAM/Processor issue?

I couldn't find more info in the [dyno documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) either except that:

> In addition, dynos are restarted as needed for the overall health of
>   the system and your app. For example, the dyno manager occasionally
>   detects a fault in the underlying hardware and needs to move your dyno
>   to a new physical location. These things happen transparently and
>   automatically on a regular basis and are logged to your application
>   logs.

Does this mean that "moving" a dyno implies a restart? Will the file system be reset? Anyone has experienced these "moves"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's supposed to happen, but I can show what did happen to a dyno I had running using `heroku run:detached`.  From the logs:

> 2017-05-02T03:55:22.317995+00:00 app[run.5217]: { callCount: 521 }
>
> 2017-05-02T03:55:47.692257+00:00 app[run.5217]: { callCount: 522 }
>
> 2017-05-02T03:56:13.157487+00:00 app[run.5217]: { callCount: 523 }
>
> 2017-05-02T03:56:29.475119+00:00 heroku[run.5217]: Relocating dyno to a new server
>
> 2017-05-02T03:56:29.483169+00:00 heroku[run.5217]: State changed from up to complete
>
> 2017-05-02T03:56:38.500261+00:00 app[run.5217]: { callCount: 524 }
>
> 2017-05-02T03:57:03.920375+00:00 app[run.5217]: { callCount: 525 }
>
> 2017-05-02T03:57:06.330797+00:00 heroku[run.5217]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>
> 2017-05-02T03:57:06.852899+00:00 heroku[run.5217]: Process exited with status 14
> 3

The callCount output is from the task itself.  I'm not sure if this implies that the dyno was working after the move and before the SIGTERM. I'm not even sure why it was shutdown; it wasn't user initiated.